# Why can't I install this module?

Tags: 8, commerce

I installed the [Commerce Shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) module (using Drupal 8), but when I try to install it, I can't do anything, neither install it nor uninstall it. The check-box is gray.

I can't find anything to configure it. Also, I can't even uninstall it to try the development snapshot version.

What should I do?

Comment: If it's not enabled, no need to uninstall, just delete the module. It requires the https://www.drupal.org/project/physical project. Did you install that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module depends on the [Physical Fields](https://drupal.org/project/physical) module. Since commerce sites are strongly strongly recommended to be managed by composer, you should be using just `composer require drupal/shipping` from the document root and be done with it.

Comment: Is it OK if I install it from the UI, cause I already did ?
How can I check before I install a module all it dependencies w/o installing it ?